# How to Start solidity programming after installing plugin in Intellij idea

Tags: solidity

I installed plug-in 'Intellij-Solidity' in Intellij Idea. But I did not found any new project option to create . Is there any environment setup for solidity programming. I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS .

Comment: I would assume the plugin is for syntax highlighting only

Comment: absolutely, Do u have any idea how to run solidity program using   Intellij idea?

Comment: @Gopalojha. I don't think you can "run" solidity programs afaiak in IntelliJ yet. Smart contracts written in solidity(.sol) are deployed on test or live net after they are compiled(using solc etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is simply smart contracts you are interested in developing you might find it easier and more supported to use [Remix online IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null) (previous version is [Browser Solidity online compiler](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/))

Comment: Thankyou for suggestion . But I want to use Intellij Idea for that .

Answer (score 4):

Starting version 2.1.0, Intellij Solidity plugin supports running solidity functions directly in IDEA. It will use an EthereumJ standalone node (refer to Solidity settings to configure/download EthereumJ)

Comment: As a Jetbrains fan, this is awesome to me!

Answer (score 2):

### Helpful tools

(truffle suite family - nodejs based)

1. [Truffle](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle) is a development environment and testing framework and asset aiming to make **life as an Ethereum developer easier**.
2. [Ganache-CLI](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) or [Ganache-GUI](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache) - Ethereum RPC client for testing and development.

(jetbrains family)

3. [IntelliJ-Solidity](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9475-intellij-solidity)   is a plugin for IntelliJ-based IDEs offers syntax highlighting, code formatting and autocomplete for Solidity files.

---

[Solidity Development: Setting up environment](https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-development-setting-up-environment-611c4bc2530b)

Comment: IntelliJ-Solidity DOES NOT allow code formatting and autocomplete for .sol files. Syntax highlight only

Comment: I guess from v2.1.0 it does [ref](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/49532/109415) - will require a EthereumJ standalone node